# Qt: *.pro vs *.pri

Tags: qt, qmake, qtcore

What is the difference between `*.pro` and `*.pri` configuration files for qmake?

What should go into a *.pro file and what should go into a *.pri file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A `.pro` file is what you would run QMake on. A `.pri` file is included by a `.pro` file. Other than that there is not much of a difference between the two.

Example usage could be if you have different builds which need different options. You could put shared information in the .pro, while deferring the options to various .pri files. A bit more information, although admittedly not much more, [can be found here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#include-filename).

Answer (score 93):

There is one main difference between their targetted reuse:

#### .pro

This is usually called *Project File*.

#### .pri

This is usually called *Project **Include** File*.

As you can see in their names, the main difference is that `.pri` files are meant to be include files. That is similar to including modules in programming language to share the functionality, essentially.

You will be able to write the common settings and code into those `.pri` files and include them from several `.pro` files as the need arises. This is how you would use it in practice:

#### foo.pri

```
FOO = BAR
```

#### hello.pro

```
...
include($$PWD/foo.pri)
...
```

#### world.pro

```
...
include($$PWD/foo.pri)
...
```

This way, the commonality would be available both in `hello.pro` as well as `world.pro`. It does not make much of difference in this scenario, but when the shared functionality gets longer, it will save you some writing as well as sync'ing, bugfixing, and so on.

You could even include a `.pri` file inside another `.pri` file if you wish. You could also include `.pri` files in different subprojects, etc. It is very nice.

The syntax is the same, however, for both the `.pro` and `.pri` files. In the end, you would run qmake on the `.pro` files, and that is also what qmake generates for you if you do not have a project file existing and you intend to use `qmake -project`.

You can read more about the include function [in here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#include-filename):

> include(filename)
>
> Includes the contents of the file specified by filename into the current project at the point where it is included. This function succeeds if filename is included; otherwise it fails. The included file is processed immediately.
>
> You can check whether the file was included by using this function as the condition for a scope.

Just to be complete, there are also `.prf` *Project **Feature** Files* and `.prl` *Project **Linker** Files*, but as an end user, you do not need to deal with that for now.

Answer (score 16):

The format of the `.pri` files is exactly the same as the format of the `.pro` files. The main difference is one of intent; a .pro is what most people would expect to run qmake on directly, while a .pri is to be included by a .pro. When you instruct qmake to include another file, it just processes the commands in that file as if it were in the current file.

For Reference: [*.pro vs *.pri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967646/using-pri-files-in-qt)

Comment: I actually saw this question and haven't noticed that *second* answer actually answers my question..:(