# Qt - Pass variable between two .pri files

Tags: qt, file, variables, cmd

I'm trying to use a flag, set from command line, such that when it is typed in, a pri file sets the variable to be used in another pri file.  The pri that sets the variable is working fine, however when I try to access the variable from another pri where it actually needs to be used, I'm not getting any results.

So for instance in cmd

```
 qmake (parameters) --variable_name
```

In parent.pri

```
 contains(options, --variable_name) {
      variable_name = true
      message("variable_name = " $$variable_name)
 }
```

output = variable_name = true

In child.pri

```
 message("variable_name = " $$variable_name)
 if(variable_name = true) {
    // do stuff
 }
 else {
     return(true)
 }
```

output = variable_name =

I believe this is the right syntax, however in the child.pri when I try to echo the value set for variable_name nothing is displayed.

I could use 
     contains(options, variable_name) {
     }

but I would like to only have to use this once in the parent.pri

Comment: How does your .pro file look like?

Answer (score 0):

[Only .pro files are executed by qmake.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358653/1122645) .pri files are a bit like headers in C and C++ in the sense that they are replaced by their contents in the pro files. So for one pri file to "know" the directives of another pri files, you need to include `parent.pri` either in `child.pri` or before `child.pri` everywhere it is included.

Comment: I've tried include(parent.pri) in the child.pri, however when running qmake, it says reading C:\blah\blah\something.pro, and then brings back the prompt

Comment: is C:\blah\blah\something.pro including child.pri?? Did you made sure paths are correct, if you include a pri file which is not found it will be silently ignored