# what is `deployment.pri` that comes with plain C++ project in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder what is this file `deployment.pri` when I create a plain C++ project. Also, is there an option to turn off adding this file with plain C++ project? I ended up removing it but I have to do this every time I create plain C++ project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358627/qt-pro-vs-pri

Comment: You have complete control over templates that come with Qt Creator. You can create your own project template that only includes exactly what you need. Simply grep for deployment.pri inside of the template folder, and you'll find the files for that template. You can copy them and make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By and large, `.pro` file uses `.pri` files to separate the **pro**ject settings (that go directly to *qmake*) and the **i**ncluded files (sources, headers, etc.).

You can customize the default project templates as you wish:

`%QTDIR%/share/qtcreator/templates` (for Windows);

`/usr/share/qtcreator/templates` (for Unix).

For example, the plain C++ template for *qmake* is stored at `%QTDIR%/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/plaincppapp/qmake/project.pro`. Simply edit this file and remove the unwanted lines (`include(deployment.pri)` in your case).