# How to use the QtVirtualKeyboard

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.7, qtvirtualkeyboard

I try to integrate the [`QtVirtualKeyboard`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html) into a prototype, but I fail.
It is the first time I work with multiple projects or where I have to include non-basic-stuff in QML/QMake-Project.

I got the code from the [*git-repository*](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git/) and were successfully running the examples. But now I am puzzled on how to integrate it into my own project.

My project structure is as follows

```
Proto (dir)
 +- Proto.pro
 +- main.cpp
 +- ...
 +---QML (dir)                     <--- QML-Files
 |    +-main.qml
 |    +---CustomControls (dir)
 |    +---...
 +---CPP (dir)                     <--- C++-Files and Headers
 +---RES                           <--- Icons and stuff
```

Now I thought I might just add the `src`-project from the virtual keyboard to the root-folder (`Proto`), and add something like:

```
SUBDIR += src/src.pro
```

to the `Proto.pro`-file
=> Yes, I can do that, but there is no merrit in it.

So what do I need to do, to actually use it? It must be really easy, for I can't find any question regarding it anywhere on google, youtube or SO.

**EDIT => I still fail.** This is my story:

I tried the *deployment*-method, followed the instructions [**here**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html).
As I'd prefer to have the keyboard within the application, I did the following:

1. I added the `make install`-stept
2. I passed `qmake` an additional argument `"CONFIG+=disable-desktop`

It seemed to work. Got new files in the mentioned directories:

- C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\*VirtualKeyboard*
- C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\*Virtualkeyboard*\*Styles*
- C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\plugins\platforminputcontexts\

Now in my project, I added the line

```
QT_IM_MODULE=qtvirtualkeyboard myapp
```

And tried to import it in my `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.0 // (also tried it with 2.1)
```

I got the error:

> [path]/main.qml:10 module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed

And that concludes my story sofar. Any suggestions where I failed?

Comment: I think you have to include `qtvirtualkeyboard.pro` into your main .pro file and so all will be done automatically

Comment: But I don't know, how to.

Comment: Copy and paste the content of `qtvirtualkeyboard.pro` into your `main.pro`.

Comment: AFAIR you can have multiple `.pri` files inside a `pro`, confirmed by Sir. lpapp himself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23845651). And by renaming a `pro` to `pri` it can be included inside your `pro`. What I do not get is why you should rebuild the keyboard module? Isn't it part of the open offer now? In any case I would compile and deploy the module. That sounds easier.

Comment: I need to rebuild the keyboard module, as - afaik - there is no pre-built module (at least for Win). I tried it with the "*compile and deploy*" but as I failed (could not import the module after) I thought maybe I got it all wrong, and tried to include it directly into my project. Probably wrong approach though :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I finally succeeded. Though it is indeed very close to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html) I don't think the documentation is easily understood. Therefor I will post this step-by-step-guid, where I will clear my own misconceptions.

1. Download the sourcecode from the [git-repository](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git/)
2. Open the project *qtvirtualkeyboard.pro* with the QtCreator, and run it with the configuration `release`
   It will create some directories and files in your Qt-installation dir. You do not need to add anything in your project directory. Once done and your good for all projects to come.
3. Make sure, you set the `QT_IM_MODULE` environment variable to include `qtvirtualkeyboard`. My mistake was, to assume (I don't know why) this might be done in the projects `.pro`-file. This seems to be wrong. The C++-method seems safe:
   `qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));`
4. If you want to have the keyboard within your application, add
   `CONFIG += disable-desktop` to your projects `.pro`-file
5. Have fun!

Comment: I cloned the repo, compiled it release build, ran make install in the build directory, checked that files `Qt/5.10.1/android_armv7/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libqtvirtualkeyboardplugin.so` and `Qt/5.10.1/android_armv7/qml/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/libqtvirtualkeyboardstylesplugin.so` are added, `QT_IM_MODULE` is set (it works for desktop version) but it still doesn't work for android: `module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed` do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience what so ever with android.

Answer (score 3):

If you select the Qt Virtual Keyboard component under a particular Qt version, you should get the prebuilt binaries:

[image: Maintenance Tool]

The Qt Enterprise Add-ons component has a virtual keyboard sub-component (?) which might only give you the sources.. not sure.

If you really need to have the module in your project's Git repo, it might be easier to just add it as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and reference that in a "3rdparty" [SUBDIRS](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies) sub-project.

Comment: It's not necessary for me to have it in my project. I just need to be able to use it and failed for the time beeing with the documentation. Now I managed to clear my misconceptions, about how to integrate it. That tool (I assume it is the from the *Install/Uninstall-Tool*) does not work, as I can't set the proxies right :-(

Comment: Can you please open a bug report about what could be improved in the documentation? What was unclear, etc. That way we can improve it.

Comment: @derM-nothereforBOTdreams It needs to be in the project due to how it runs I think.