# Shared preprocessing macro definition among multiple sub-projects, i.e. shared libraries

Tags: c++, qt, c-preprocessor, qt-creator

I have a project with multiple **sub-projects**. One sub-project for **executable** and the rest for **shared libraries**. Each sub-project has its own `*.pro` file.

I need to define a compiler preprocessing macro, but I don't want to repeat defining it in each `*.pro` file. Is it possible to **share** a macro definition among multiple sub-projects?

---

My sample preprocessing macro:

```cpp
#define PI 3.1415926
```

Adding to `*.pro` files:

```cpp
DEFINES += "PI=\"3.1415926\""
```

Comment: Did you consider to use a `*.pri` file and include it in your `.pro` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: \*.pro vs \*.pri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358627/qt-pro-vs-pri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your macro in a .pri file (config.pri, for example) and include this .pri file in each .pro files for your sub-projects.

config.pri

```
DEFINES += "PI=\"3.1415926\""
```

sub_project.pro

```
include (/path/to/config.pri)
```

This forces you to modify each sub-projects .pro files though.

Comment: As @vahancho suggested in a comment, the `*.pri` files are usually used for this purpose, right?

Comment: Well, [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358627/3405291) there is not much technical difference between `*.pro` and `*.pri`

Comment: still it is a convention to use .pri instead of pro for `include` directives

Comment: Yes indeed. I was not aware of this .pri naming convention (https://wiki.qt.io/Including_.pro_Files). I'm editing the answer.