# How to create a folder or a subdirectory for a project in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to create subdirectories and folders to organise my code in Qt.

I tried to manually create the directory in my shell / explorer, but Qt does not recognize it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prior to QT Creator 3.1.x, you can **right-click on your project** -> "**add new...**" and **change the path to the folder you want.**

[image: Qt add new...]

Be careful the folder must exist, Qt will not create it for you.

[image: Add a new class and change the default folder Qt]

Qt takes care of the path in your .pro file.

[image: Qt takes care of the path in your .pro file]

[image: Qt takes care of the path in your .pro file]

That's it !