# QT - "No rule to make target" after renaming file in hierarchy

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm willing to create subfolders in Qt Creator, using answers from the following thread :

[How to create a folder or a subdirectory for a project in QtCreator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959959/how-to-create-a-folder-or-a-subdirectory-for-a-project-in-qtcreator)

I created a folder in my explorer, then renamed my existing file "folder/existingFile.cpp". (I also did it for the header .h)
The file is successfully show in the hierarchy under the new folder. 
I cleaned the project, run qmake.

At compilation the following error is thrown:

> No rule to make target "[...]/existingFile.cpp" needed by
>   'qrc_app.cpp'.  Stop.

*Is my make file generated by qmake corrupted ?*

*What am I doing wrong ?*

Ps : I tried the .pri approach suggested in the thread (.pri in subfolder, including it in the .pro) without success.

Comment: I think you have removed a file imported in your resources file (.qrc).

Comment: Thanks, It did the trick ! Renaming the file does not remove it from the app.qrc, but moves it in new folder; resulting in compilation error because path changed. You rocks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Qt resources file (*.qrc) is a XML file containing the paths to your resources. It isn't automatically updated when you move/delete files outide the Qt resource editor.

So, when you delete a file without removing it from the resource file, the build will still try to embed it and will fail.

Comment: You should have included a solution in your answer