# How to add property to custom control in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I properly add a property to a custom control, which when changed triggers the paint event? The property only accepts an integer value of 0, 1 or 2.

The setter of the property would be called **setPattern**, so an example use would be **setPattern(0)**.

This property value will eventually be used to control the pattern drawn in the paint event.

labelheader.h

```
#ifndef LABELHEADER_H
#define LABELHEADER_H

#include <QLabel>

class LabelHeader : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LabelHeader(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    explicit LabelHeader(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:

    // QWidget interface
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};

#endif // LABELHEADER_H
```

labelheader.cpp

```
#include "labelheader.h"
#include <QPainter>

LabelHeader::LabelHeader(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{

}

LabelHeader::LabelHeader(const QString &text, QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(text, parent)
{

}

void LabelHeader::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    // calculate font width
    QFontMetrics metrics(font());
    int text_width = metrics.boundingRect(text()).width();

    // calculate dimensions
    int y = height() * 0.5;
    int x = text_width + 4;

    // create pattern
    QPixmap px(4, 4);
    px.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter pattern_painter(&px);

    // Create ashed 3 dots
    pattern_painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    pattern_painter.setBrush(QBrush(palette().color(QPalette::WindowText), Qt::SolidPattern));
    pattern_painter.drawRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    pattern_painter.drawRect(2, 2, 1, 1);

    // draw
    QPainter painter(this);

    // Draw dashed 3 dots
    painter.drawTiledPixmap(x, y-2, width()-x, 5, px);

    // Draw solid line
    //painter.drawLine(x,y,width(),y);

    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by property? Property registered by `Q_PROPERTY`? What exactly from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#a-simple-example) isn't clear?

Comment: Yeah exactly like that, how would i make it trigger a paint event when the value is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

To accomplish what you need you **do not actually need QProperty**, but a **private attribute** of your `LabelHeader` class. Here is a step-by-step guide, covering all your requirements:

1. Create the enumeration type

In *LabelHeader.h* add:

```
enum PatternType {
    PatternOne = 0,
    PatternTwo,
    PatternThree
};
```

2. Declare a private attribute to hold the current pattern

In *LabelHeader.h* add:

```
private:
    PatternType m_pattern;
```

3. Right click `m_pattern` and select *Refactor->Create Getter and Setter Member Functions*
4. In the implementation of the setter invoke a `paintEvent` by calling `update()`, but only if the new pattern is different than the current one:

   ```
   if (m_pattern == pattern)
       return;

   m_pattern = pattern;
   update();
   ```
5. In the constructor add `m_pattern` to the initializer list to set its value by default
6. Use the value in the `LabelHeader::paintEvent` to draw the corresponding pattern

   ```
   // draw tiled pixmap
   QPainter painter(this);

   switch (m_pattern) {
   case PatternOne:
       painter.drawTiledPixmap(x, y-2, w, 5, px);
       break;
   case PatternTwo:
       painter.drawTiledPixmap(x, y, w, 5, px);
       break;
   default:
       painter.drawTiledPixmap(x, y+2, w, 5, px);
   }
   ```

## Example

I have extended the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277895/5366641) to cover your current requirements as well. The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-LabelHeader).

## Remarks

Regarding the use of `Q_PROPERTY`, here is an important explanation kindly provided by @KubaOber:

> Q_PROPERTY is a Qt idiom used to both convey a meaning to a human
>   reader, and expose the property as such to the metatype system, making
>   it easily scriptable from QML, etc.

Comment: Do you have any pros or cons on why i shouldn't or should use QProperty?

Comment: not quite sure what this is for or if it's a type in your example m_pattesrn line 28 of the header file

Comment: @JokerMartini, I am sorry, it was a mistake. It is fixed now. Thank you for mentioning that! As for the QProperty, there is nothing wrong with it. I've mentioned that explicitly, because you said that you are new to C++ and the proper term for what you need is a class attribute. Property is understood as QProperty. Just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: You are 100% correct, I needed a class attribute. Thank you for that :)

Comment: Do you happen to do freelance work at all? Just curious to know?

Comment: `Q_PROPERTY` is a Qt idiom used to *both* convey a meaning to a human reader, *and* expose the property as such to the metatype system, making it easily scriptable from QML, etc. Everything in this answer is correct, but orthogonal to the use of `Q_PROPERTY` - which is still required.

Comment: It should also perhaps be made explicit that the setter (`setPattern`) should compare the new setting to the current one, and do nothing if they are equal - the update then would be redundant, and it may simplify other code if the assumption that setting the same value multiple times is cheap. It is in all of Qt's property setters, so making the user code depart from that ideal, while not dramatically bad, may come as unexpected, and can certainly introduce performance bugs.

Comment: @KubaOber, you are completely right, of course. My point was not *do not use QProperty*, but *this is not the proper term*, as the OP mentioned in a connected question, that he comes from Python and is new to C++. Again, thanks for the valuable input! I will modify the code and the answer accordingly.

Comment: @scopchanov did you update your github to reflect the suggestions made by Kuba. I would like to see the proper and recommended way of writing this in code.

Comment: @JokerMartini, yes, I just did.

Comment: @scopchanov ok great, ill check it out. I'd like to make sure i am doing this proper and i appreciate you guys all so kindly helping. Do you do paid freelance work at all as well. I was curious?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `update()` in the setter. If you want to only accept limited range of values, you can limit that in a setter or use an enum instead of an int.

```
#include <QLabel>

class LabelHeader : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(Pattern pattern READ(getPattern) WRITE(setPattern))

    enum Pattern { FIRST = 0, SECOND, THIRD };
    Q_ENUM(Pattern)

...

    void setPattern(Pattern value)
    {
        if (pattern != value)
        {
            pattern = value;
            update();
        }
    }

    Pattern getPattern() const { return pattern; }
...

private:
    Pattern pattern { FIRST };
};
```

Comment: I like the enum idea much more like you suggested. If you have an example or modify this to showcase that, much appreciated :)

Comment: because the one thing I'm also curious about is how to i define the default enum value

Comment: @JokerMartini: I've updated the question. It's basically the exact example from the documentation I linked to your question...

Comment: @JokerMartini I dunno about newer Qt version s(above 5.1) but  before that enum was a way to get a sore rump, trying to figure out what you did wrong IF you use  Designer. Designer didn't work properly with enums. Even with Q_ENUM used. Worse, if you try to use  stylesheets with selectors by enum values taken from Widget properties, that seem  to not work even now.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.  NOTE: I haven't written an actual custom control in a "library", I usually just use "promoted widgets".

Header File:

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>

class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value WRITE setValue)

    private:
        int m_value;

    public:
        MyWidget(QWidget *parent=0);

        inline int value() const {return m_value;}
        void setValue(int value);

    signals:
        void valueChanged();
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

Source File:

```
#include "MyWidget.h"

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget(parent)
{
    m_value = 0;
}

void MyWidget::setValue(int value)
{
    if (m_value == value) return;

    m_value = value;
    emit valueChanged();

    update();   // This will cause repaint
}
```

Comment: And that is, indeed, how it should be done. The `QObject` header is redundant, though - in fact, headers for *all* base classes are redundant, only the most derived class's header should be included, for the entire class forest.

Comment: @KubaOber, yes you are right about the headers, surely QWidget already include QObject.  Added it before I decided to derive from QWidget as an example.  Although, I have had times where the Qt Creator intellisense seems to work better if Qt classes is explicitly included.  It shouldn't really be a problem or cause a significant compile time hit, because QObject likely has include guards.